# Asymptotic behavior of Euclidean correlators in QCD

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics

I am reading an old review paper (http://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.65.1). In the beginning it makes the following statement (I copy with slightly different notation). If we consider mesonic and baryonic operators:
\begin{eqnarray}
O_m \sim \bar{\Psi}_i \Psi_j M_{ij} \\
O_b \sim \Psi_i \Psi_j \Psi_k N_{ijk}
\end{eqnarray}
where $i,j,k$ are flavour, spin, Dirac indices lumped together in a multiindex, M and N are some coefficients. Now, if we consider Euclidean correlators of these operators, the asymptotic form at small separations is dictated by asymptotic freedom. So, since the free quark propagator scales as $\left< \bar{\Psi}(x) \Psi(0) \right> \sim 1/x^3$, we get for the corrrelator of mesonic operators $~1/x^6$ and for the baryonic case $~1/x^9$. This kind of results comes from basic dimensional arguments.

My question is: is this statement true? Shouldn't there be an anomalous dimenionsion here?